# Is it possible to move a schema to another database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We have a legacy database that has dozens of schemas in it, and we're looking to split that database up into several smaller distinct databases instead.

Is there any way I can create a new database on the same physical server, and then transfer an entire schema over to the new database?

Our tables look like:

```
Foo.Table1
Foo.Table2
Foo.Table3
...
Bar.Table1
Bar.Table2
...
Xxx.Table1
Xxx.Table2
...
```

...and I want to move `Foo.*` to a new database.

Typically this is recommended to be done by some kind of per-table export/import, but that's quite cumbersome with the 150+ tables in the schema.

As far as my trivial research goes the options appear to be:

- Export/import each table individually.
- Backup the entire database, restore in a different destination and delete everything else (painful, since the entire database is ~900GB).
- Deploy the dacpac of the single schema to the new database, and do a cross database initial seeding, aka:

```
INSERT INTO newDb.Foo.Table1 SELECT * FROM oldDb.Foo.Table1;
INSERT INTO newDb.Foo.Table2 SELECT * FROM oldDb.Foo.Table2;
INSERT INTO newDb.Foo.Table3 SELECT * FROM oldDb.Foo.Table3;
...
```

All of these options are a lot of effort... is there any other approach that will simply move an entire schema into a new database?

Comment: This might be better suited for [dba.se] It would seem like you'd stand a better chance of getting an answer there rather than here.

Comment: Agree with Ken - short answer - no.

Comment: @KenWhite fair call; is there a way to move a question, or should I close this one and lodge it as a new question there?

Comment: You can either wait until it gets enough migrate votes (it has 3 of the 5 needed now) or you can just [edit] the post, select all of the text, and Ctrl+C to copy, cancel the edit, delete the post, and then go to the other site and paste it into a new question. That retains all of the formatting and content, and you'll just need to add a title and tags. Whichever you prefer is up to you, but if you post at the other site please delete it here. Cross-site posting is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any fully automated way but this can be done relatively simply with the help of Excel.

In SSMS you can use "Object Explorer **Details**" to easily (with few mouse clicks) script schema of multiple tables.

With the help of system views (`sys.tables`, `sys.columns` etc.) and Excel you should be able to generate 'INSERT INTO .... SELECT ...' scripts for all of your tables in minutes.

In Excel (or a similar application) you paste the list of your tables (obtained using `sys.tables`) and then write a formula to generate a script for each table.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a filegroup for each schema and move the tables of a schema into the related filegroup. after that you backup each filegroup and restore.